# How to create a rosbag file with messages with an header

Tags: ros, rosbag, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

As I wrote on the title I'm trying to create a rosbag file from another one changing message types and using only some topics from the original one. The problem is, when I play the new rosbag the messages type is Float32, thus headerless.

Does someone know how can I write messages with an header (Float32Stamped or what else) in the new rosbag, without any error?
I read that the last parameter of the write function is connection_header, but I didn't find anything that explain something about it. In the following, the code.

Thank you for the help

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rosbag
from marti_common_msgs.msg import Float32Stamped


with rosbag.Bag('try.bag', 'w') as outbag:
    for topic, msg, t in rosbag.Bag('20180810150607_bus_signals.bag').read_messages():
        if '/value' in topic:
            fmsg = Float32Stamped()
            fmsg.header = t
            fmsg.value = msg
            outbag.write(topic,fmsg.value, fmsg.header if fmsg._has_header else t)
        else:
            continue    
outbag.close()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365806/how-to-create-a-rosbag-file-with-messages-with-an-header/) by [EdoardoSerri](https://answers.ros.org/users/63458/edoardoserri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2020-11-17**:
Wouldn't fmsg._has_header have the same value for every message in the bag file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

header is not timestamp.
header contains seq, timesamp, and frame_id.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rosbag
from marti_common_msgs.msg import Float32Stamped

with rosbag.Bag('try.bag', 'w') as outbag:
    for topic, msg, t in rosbag.Bag('20180810150607_bus_signals.bag').read_messages():
        if '/value' in topic:
            fmsg = Float32Stamped()
            fmsg.header.stamp = t  # <== This line changed to use fmsg.header.stamp
            fmsg.value = msg
            outbag.write(topic, fmsg, t)
        else:
            continue    
outbag.close()
```

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2